# PHP connecting to OpenLDAP without Fully Distinguished Name

Tags: php, ldap, openldap

I am attempting to replicate a Microsoft AD environment utilizing OpenLDAP on Ubuntu so that I can have a test environment for my web applications.  The issue I am running into is that the ldap_bind command returns the error "Invalid DN syntax" unless I use the fully distinguished username to connect in OpenLDAP, however this is not an issue on the Microsoft side of things.  Is there a way to force OpenLDAP to search its directory for that user to authenticate against versus having to use the fully distinguished name?  Thanks for the help.

*Edit*
Here is what doesn't work but would be the goal:

```
$ad = ldap_connect('ldap://localhost') or die("Could not connect!");
// Set version number
ldap_set_option($ad, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3) or die("Could not set ldap protocol");
ldap_set_option($ad, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0) or die("Could not set ldap protocol");
// Binding to ldap server
$bd = ldap_bind($ad, 'admin', 'Password1') or die("Couldn't Connect");
```

And here is what works:

```
$ad = ldap_connect('ldap://localhost') or die("Could not connect!");
// Set version number
ldap_set_option($ad, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3) or die("Could not set ldap protocol");
ldap_set_option($ad, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0) or die("Could not set ldap protocol");
// Binding to ldap server
$bd = ldap_bind($ad, 'cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com', 'Password1') or die("Couldn't Connect");
```

Comment: Can you edit some examples into your question?  How about a working connection and a not-working connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes AD, does use a [neat trick](http://ldapwiki.willeke.com/wiki/Ambiguous%20Name%20Resolution) to find the FDN from some attributes. I do wish some of the other LDAP server vendors would implement something similar.

You will need to bind as a user with sufficient rights to locate and read the user's attributes and pass the FDN to the bind for the user.